# One of the loops I've made seems to be 10x as slow

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, for-loop

I came across something quite weird in my application; one loop seems to process an array of 300000 items just fine, while another loop seems to process an array like this at 1/20th of the speed.

These are my loops:

```
let alength = allsetcards.length; // usually +/- 300000 items in this array, loop takes +/- 3 seconds
for (let y = 0; y < alength; y++) { // this is the faster loop
    console.log("aloop: " + y);
    let i = allsetcards[y];
    setassetids.push(i.assetid); // this is basically .map but as a for loop because its faster
}

let ilength = currentinv.length; // 300000 - 400000 items in this array, loop takes longer than 1 minute
for (let y = 0; y < ilength; y++) { // this is the terribly slow loop
    console.log("iloop " + y);
    let i = currentinv[y], // array of objects with with 6 keys/values
            assetid = i.assetid; // thought this might make it somewhat faster
    if (!sets[i.game] || setassetids.indexOf(assetid) < 0) nosets.push(i); // filtering some stuff out (because .filter is even slower)
}
```

It seems very strange that indexOf or .push(object) would take so much longer, so I think something else that I haven't quite figured out yet might be wrong.

What I have tried to fix this is filling the nosets array with all items that are being filtered in the slow loop, then using .splice(y, 1) to filter it. This didn't help at all.

I really hope someone knows why exactly this is happening!

Thanks, Tim

SOLVED: I was using .indexOf in the second loop, causing it to have to do 300000^2 times as much work as the first loop, what I did to prevent this from happening was make setassetids an object, with keys being the assetid and the values being a true value so I can use setassetids[assetid] to check whether it exists or not! (thanks to @Fefux and @t.niese)

Comment: In your second loop you search `300000 - 400000` times in an array that has `300000` elements, so only in the best case if `assetid` is always the first element, it would have the same speed as the first one. In the worst case if `assetid` is the last element or if it does not exists in that array, js would need to look at `300000 * 400000` items.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Thanks so much! I will see what I can do to do this in another way! :)

But why would the loop be 20x as slow though? Is that just the speed of indexOf?

Comment: Just curious, how did you figure out how much time each loop takes to execute? I have seen map vs for comparisons behave differently on different browsers. For example - https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6

Comment: if `assetid` is a compatible object key string and if you don't care about memory, you can transform `setassetids` to an object. Instead of doing `setassetids.push(i.assetid)`, you do `setassetids[i.assetid] = true` and in your second loop you can just test if the key exist instead of search if value exist in array.

Comment: You probably could use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), or an Object for `setassetids`. Something like `setassetids = {}`and then `setassetids[i.assetid] = true` and instead of `setassetids.indexOf(assetid)` you could use `setassetids[assetid]`, but I don't have time to test how it would perform on this number of elements.

Comment: You cannot be precise as to the speed is 20x slower or 30x. Its only one data set that you are studying. You will need to run with sevaral permutation/ combinations of data to arrive at any such figure. One thing is for sure as @t.niese pointed out, indexof will cost you as it would be a linear search only.

Comment: @VamshiGudipati I timed the time it took to process 10000 items. The arrays Im testing with are always the same and are a good representation of what my app would have to deal with

Comment: @Fefux thanks for the idea! ill see how the memory turn out, but I think its fine :) tyty

Comment: If your browser constraints allow for it, ES6 has a Set type, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @RajeevRanjan true, the problem was only occuring with very big arrays so I was trying to fix that. It was only a problem with a big array like this because the slow-ness would grow exponentially based on the array length (because it would loop 300000 times through a loop 300000 big) Anyway, Im happy that this is finally resolved! :)